# How to flag inappropriate Edits

Tags: discussion, moderation, editing

Whilst reviewing the Edits queue - I saw a suggested edit that added a crude personal insult to the post.

There are edits which I may reject because I disagree with the Edit being made, whereas this one exceeded a threshold of discretion and requires Mod intervention. I feel uncomfortable posting a public question, but I'm not sure how to flag an edit for Mod review or how to contact the Mod team privately.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Flag the post in question which needs Mod attention (the one with the Suggested Edit), so we can check on the Edit History and other info.